# Capistrano skips deploy:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, capistrano

I have the following in my `deploy.rb`:

```
after "deploy:update_code", "sphinx:stop"
after "deploy:migrate", "sphinx:start"
```

Often when I issue a `cap` command, sometimes the changes don't require a `deploy:migrate`, and went to `deploy:restart` as its final command. Hence, `sphinx:start` was not issued and I had to restart Sphinx manually.

I could have done this:

```
after "deploy:update_code", "sphinx:stop"
after "deploy:migrate", "sphinx:start"
after "deploy:restart", "sphinx:start"
```

But I don't wanna do this because if a `deploy:migrate` is required and issued, Sphinx would be started twice. What should be the proper command line? Or might as well just replace `deploy:migrate` with `deploy:restart`?

```
after "deploy:update_code", "sphinx:stop"
after "deploy:restart", "sphinx:start"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
after "deploy:update_code", "sphinx:stop"
after "deploy:restart", "sphinx:start"
```

This worked.